# Can't access SharePoint API from script but can from browser

Tags: development, powershell, sharepoint-rest-api

My site url looks like this

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ADV-DEV/assigDev/bassie/sitePages/home.aspx
```

I created a test list to try out the api and managed to get the list items using a SharePoint REST client addin and also managed to get that data by just going to this url in the browser

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ADV-DEV/assigDev/bassie/_api/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items
```

However, when trying to access the same from both PowerShell and C# I keep getting an error

> 403 Forbidden

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ADV-DEV/assigDev/bassie/_api/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'GET' -Uri $url -Credential $Cred
```

How is this possible? Is there some permission I need which is specifically for using the API from a script or program?

I tried getting my username with

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ADV-DEV/assigDev/bassie/_api/web/CurrentUser
```

Which shows `loginname` as

```
i:0#.f|membership|user.name@company.com
```

But I still get `403` when logging in with that

Comment: Is this for Office 365/SharePoint Online, or for on-prem SharePoint? If for online, then you need to get the X-RequestDigest value and add it to the header of your request. Do a search for "sharepoint online rest c#" or "sharepoint online rest PowerShell" for examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try it as below:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'

$siteUrl = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ADV-DEV/assigDev/bassie"
$Username = "user.name@company.com"
$Password = "password"

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force))
$Context.ExecuteQuery()    

$RequestUrl = "$($siteUrl)/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test')/items"
$AuthenticationCookie = $Context.Credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie($siteUrl, $true)

$WebSession = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$WebSession.Credentials = $Context.Credentials
$WebSession.Cookies.SetCookies($siteUrl, $AuthenticationCookie)
$WebSession.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -WebSession $WebSession -Uri $RequestUrl

$Context.Dispose()

Write-Output $Result
```

Change your path of the dlls, site collection and list as per that in your environment.

If you dont have the files at that location, download and install the SharePoint Online Client Components SDK.

In case you need to perform `POST` queries, you will need to get the `FormDigestValue`. To do so, just add to previous $websession config:

```
$formDigest = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -WebSession $WebSession -Uri "$targetSiteUrl/_api/contextinfo" -errorAction Stop 
$WebSession.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", $formDigest.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue)
$queryResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -WebSession $WebSession -Uri $restQuery-errorAction Stop
```

Download link  - [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Answer (score 1):

RestSPO.ps1:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$UserName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[String]$Password
)

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime") | Out-Null


if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Password)) {
   $SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password" -AsSecureString 
}
else {
   $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
}


$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($Url)
$request.Credentials = $credentials
$request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
$request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose"
$request.Method=$Method
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$requestStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
$readStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $requestStream
$data=$readStream.ReadToEnd()
$results = $data | ConvertFrom-Json
$results.d.results
```

and then invoke it using below:

```
 .\RestSPO.ps1 -Url "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ADV-DEV/assigDev/bassie/_api/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items" -UserName "username@tenant.microsoft.com" -Password "password"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer deepmala. I want to try this, but I don't have the files you specified at `Add-Type`. Do you know where I can find those?

Comment: Updated the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Another option I managed to get working was to first retrieve a security token from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf`, and then an access token from `https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0`:

```
$Global:Credential = Get-Credential -Message "cred" -UserName "bassie.surname@COMPANY.com"

function Get-StringBetweenTwoStrings($firstString, $secondString, $inputString){
    #Regex pattern to compare two strings
    $pattern = "$firstString(.*?)$secondString"

    #Perform the opperation
    $result = [regex]::Match($inputString,$pattern).Groups[1].Value

    #Return result
    return $result
}
function Get-AuthCookies {
    $body = 
@"
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
      xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
      xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
       xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <o:UsernameToken>
        <o:Username>$($Global:Credential.UserName)</o:Username>
        <o:Password>MyPassword</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
      <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <a:EndpointReference>
          <a:Address>https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/sites/ADV-DEV/assigDev/bassie/_api</a:Address>
        </a:EndpointReference>
      </wsp:AppliesTo>
      <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
      <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
      <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
    </t:RequestSecurityToken>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
"@

    $securityTokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf"
    $accessTokenUrl = "https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0"

    $secTokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Body $body -Uri $securityTokenUrl -Method POST

    $token = $secTokenResponse.Envelope.Body.RequestSecurityTokenResponse.RequestedSecurityToken.BinarySecurityToken.InnerText

    $accTokenResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Body $token -Uri $accessTokenUrl -Method POST 

    $cookieHeaders = $accTokenResponse.Headers.'Set-Cookie'

    return $cookieHeaders
}
```

We then want to use these tokens to construct some cookies which we will send with the web request:

```
$cookie = Get-AuthCookies 
$rtFa = Get-StringBetweenTwoStrings -firstString "rtFa=" -secondString ";" -inputString $cookie
$FedAuth = Get-StringBetweenTwoStrings -firstString "FedAuth=" -secondString ";" -inputString $cookie

$url = "https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/sites/ADV-DEV/assigDev/bassie/_api/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items"
[System.Uri]$Uri = $url
$ContentType = "application/json" 
$Method = 'GET' 

$Cookie1 = New-Object System.Net.Cookie
$Cookie1.Name = "rtFa" # Add the name of the cookie
$Cookie1.Value = $rtFa
$Cookie1.Domain = $uri.DnsSafeHost

$Cookie2 = New-Object System.Net.Cookie
$Cookie2.Name = "FedAuth" # Add the name of the cookie
$Cookie2.Value = $FedAuth
$Cookie2.Domain = $uri.DnsSafeHost

$WebSession = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$WebSession.Cookies.Add($Cookie1)
$WebSession.Cookies.Add($Cookie2)
```

Finally, send the web request.

```
# Splat the parameters
$props = @{
    Uri         = $uri.AbsoluteUri
    Credential  = $Credential
    ContentType = $ContentType
    Method      = $Method
    WebSession  = $WebSession
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @props
$response.content.properties.Title
```

While this does work, it is pretty long-winded and unnecessarily complicated.

I ended up just using the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` library in C# to do what I needed - as all this needs is my credentials without the need to supply tokens..

I then realised I can use that same library in PowerShell with

```
$loadInfo1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$loadInfo2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
```